# How read the json in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Can you tell me how to read the json in javascript?

I have a json string as bellow

```
 {"person":{"First name":"Dharmalingm","Last name":"Arumugam","Address":{"door number":"123","street":"sample street","city":"sample_city"},"phone number":{"mobile":"0123","landline":"01234","skype":"01235"}}}
```

I want to read the **skype** phone number

Comment: Don't try to read the string. JSON **IS** javascript, it can be trivially converted into a native javascript object/array: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  Do you have the above JSON as a string value (i.e. `"{"person":{...}}"`) or as an object (i.e. `{"person":{...}}`)?

Comment: Is this the response to an AJAX call, or is it available when the initial page is rendered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you on your way.

```
var o = {"person":{"First name":"Dharmalingm","Last name":"Arumugam","Address":{"door number":"123","street":"sample street","city":"sample_city"},"phone number":{"mobile":"0123","landline":"01234","skype":"01235"}}}

o["person"]["phone number"]["skype"];

/* or */

o.person["phone number"]["skype"];
```

Comment: If you don't have the "string" available in JavaScript as in this example (for instance if you get it from an external source) you should try @Joseph the Dreamer's answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you are starting out with a JSON string, start with `1`. If you already have a JS object, then skip to `2`.

1. Parse the string using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert JSON string to a JS object. To support [a browser that does not have the native JSON](http://caniuse.com/#search=json), you can use [Crockford's JSON2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to implement it.

   ```
   var jsondata = JSON.parse('{"person":{"First name":"Dharmalingm","Last name":"Arumugam","Address":{"door number":"123","street":"sample street","city":"sample_city"},"phone number":{"mobile":"0123","landline":"01234","skype":"01235"}}}');
   ```
2. Retrieve the value like you normally would from a JS object

   ```
   var skype = jsondata.person['phone number'].skype;
   ```

Here's the full code and [a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/3cCej/):

```
var jsondata = JSON.parse('{"person":{"First name":"Dharmalingm","Last name":"Arumugam","Address":{"door number":"123","street":"sample street","city":"sample_city"},"phone number":{"mobile":"0123","landline":"01234","skype":"01235"}}}');

//normally, the dot-notation is used
//but since "phone number" is not a valid key when using dot-notation
//the bracket notation is used
var skype = jsondata.person['phone number'].skype;
```

Answer (score 0):

First it needs to be parsed out to a native javascript object, in modern browsers this can be done via `JSON.parse(json string here);`.  Now to specifically get to the skype number you have the object you just parsed out. Let's pretend you assigned it via `var skypeData = JSON.parse(json string here);`, the persons skype number is accessible via `skypeData.person['phone number'].skype`. We have to use `['phone number']` instead of `person.phone number.skype` because of the space.